# Enviar varios datos al cliente con websocket y mostrarlos

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Quisiera que alguien me ayudara a encontrar luces porque no consigo lo que busco con el código que tengo:

```
var track = (event.data); // en esta variable recibo los datos enviados por web socket...
console.log (track); // esta variable me muestra esto:

media/m3u/merengue.m3u 
media/m3u/salsa.m3u 
media/m3u/pop.m3u 
media/m3u/regueton.m3u 
media/m3u/romanticas.m3u 
media/m3u/offline.m3u
```

Lo que necesito es separarlos y crearle una variable a cada link con su respectivo nombre m3u, para poder usarlos por separados...

Tengo 6 botones con el nombre de cada uno, que al pulsar llamará a cada variable y la usare en otro código.

- Probé usando `track.length`.
- Probé usando `for (i=0; i < 6 ; i++){ var test = ([i] + track )}` tampoco funciona.
- Use `track $.each, function {...}` error de consola *no puedo usar serch in*...

Cuando intento recorrer me arroja esto todo el tiempo:

[image: lo que muestra la consola]

En la foto convertí la variable en array con:

```
 var track = [event.data] //corchetes.
 console.log (track) // muestra la imagen que está arriba todo los link son 0 y no hay enumeración igual con length 1.
```

**Nota:** Ya me he paseado por JQuery viendo ejemplos de array's como este:

```
 colores = [verde, amarillo, rojo] 
  
 console.log(colores[1]);
```

Resultado amarillo, entiendo que verde es 0, esto no me funciona tampoco, la consola arroja `undefined`.

Creo que existe otro método para estos casos en particular pero no lo he encontrado porque quizás no formulo la pregunta correctamente en google...

Tengo 2 días googleando, leyendo y probando y nada ha funcionado...

gracias de antemano por su ayuda...

Comment: Trata de incluir la información que actualizaste en la pregunta y no como respuesta. Ahora bien.. entiendo tu problema y es que estás recorriendo track el cual solo tiene un item dentro, por eso siempre es 0 el índice y el length es 1. De hecho si quieres acceder al item solo debes poner track[0].. eso es todo.

Comment: track tiene 0 y un length, pero adentro se encuentran 5 links... el problema es que los 5 link estan en 1 solo length... y no puedo recorrerlos para separarlos... claro si coloco track[0], se ven los 5 link, pero aun no puedo jugar con ello separadamente en variables que es lo que quiero... sacarlos de alli individualmente

Comment: Crea una nueva variable que sea const data = track.flat() y recorre esa variable data. Coméntanos que tal te va

Comment: nota como comentario: webaocket me envia 5 links, no en un solo send, sino 5 send... uyyy comentando esto me estoy dando cuenta, que ese es el problema, que los 5 link no se envian simultaneos sino uno despues del otro y por eso no se pueden recorrer en la variable track.... alli podria estar el problema,,, ya que los 5 no llegan en el mismo momento de dar click y correr el codigo... a pesar de que se muestran los 5 links, pero es porque al refrescar la pagina ya se han cargado en un solo length

Comment: A eso iba con mi respuesta... que cada link que llega debes unificarlo para poder recorrerlo

Comment: disculpa no soy tan rucho en la programacion de javascript o jquery, pero como los unifico?

Comment: Haciendo lo que te recomende en la respuesta... Tienes que esperar que lleguen los 5 links y despues agregas cada link `[...link1, ...link2, ...link3]`

Comment: los 5 link no se envian como variables sino como mensaje o sea asi:ws.send('media/m3u/merengue.m3u');
      ws.send('media/m3u/salsa.m3u');
      ws.send('media/m3u/pop.m3u');
      ws.send('media/m3u/regueton.m3u');
      ws.send('media/m3u/romanticas.m3u');
      ws.send('media/m3u/offline.m3u');  y del otro lado se recoje en event.data y este a su vez lo guardo en una variable track ...

Comment: no los puedo unificar ya que llegan por el misma variable que se llama event.data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solución:

web socket solo permite enviar un solo mensaje directo, y para enviar multiples mensajes en uno solo como en mi caso, se debe utilizar JSON. mi código de envío quedo asi:

```
ws.send(JSON.stringify({merengue: 'media/m3u/merengue.m3u', salsa: 'media/m3u/salsa.m3u', pop: "media/m3u/pop.m3u", regueton: "media/m3u/regueton.m3u" , romanticas: "media/m3u/romanticas.m3u", offline: "media/m3u/offline.m3u"}));
```

// En este caso ya mis link están identificados por nombre. Luego en mi cliente js. coloco

```
 ws.addEventListener('message', event => {     
 const track = JSON.parse(event.data); // recojo mis datos JSON y lo coloco en una variable 

 var merengue = (track[merengue]); // recojo mi link con su nombre identificador
 console.log (merengue) // muestro mi link por consola 

 });
 {merengue: 'media/m3u/merengue.m3u'} // resultado por consola
```

y listo eso es todo... lo dejo por acá por si alguien le sirve...

Comment: Gran respuesta!

Answer (score 0):

Estas utilizando mal la variable, porque por cada vuelta del ciclo estas reemplazando el valor de **test**.

Ahora bien, lo que te devuelve el `websocket` es un arreglo por cada ítem, por lo que deberías utilizar los **[spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Sintaxis_Spread)** para unificar todo en una sola variable y de esta manera, poder acceder mediante su posición. Algo así

```
const aux = [...data1, ...data2, ...data3];
```

Te dejo un ejemplo

```js
const test = () => {
   const data1 = ["media/m3u/merengue.m3u"];
   const data2 = ["media/m3u/salsa.m3u"];
   const data3 = ["media/m3u/pop.m3u"];

   const aux = [...data1, ...data2, ...data3];
   console.log(aux)
};
test();
```

Comment: A que te refieres con que no lo enumeró? Podrías incluir un ejemplo del resultado que quieres?

Comment: @FranciscoToro ya entendí la problemática y edita la respuesta!

Comment: el resultado es el mismo ya de por si el codigo solo hace eso... var = [event.data]; ya con esto se convierte en el mismo arreglo que arriba mencionas en tu codigo. el problema está en recorrerlo... voy a poner una fotocon dos tipos de codigos..

Comment: este codigo me funciona a medias... enumera pero repetitivamente

      for (let i = 0; i < track.length; i++) {
        console.log(` ${i} |  ${track}`);
      }  

[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UbvLg.png

solo tendria que eliminar que me repita el mismo link 6 veces... eso seria todo

Comment: ya lo solucioné... el problema estaba del lado del servidor websocket, la solución fue enviar los link en forma de JSON y luego recogerlos y mostrarlos... asi me funcionó

Comment: Excelente! Considera incluir tu solución para futuros problemas similares. Feliz código!

Comment: gracias pablo por tomarte la molestia de ayudarme por tu gran ayuda y aporte desinteresado... estoy agradecido... exitos amigo.